# Async html import only working on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, pageload

Hey folks I have a problem with this jQuery snippet that I found on the web. As it only loads the content when I reload the website but not on initial page load.

```js
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('[data-async-url]').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                url = $this.data('async-url');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'get',
                success: function(html) {
                    $this.replaceWith(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Any suggestions and/or ideas/help is much appreciated.

Comment: To the JS engine a load is no different to a re-load, so I don't see how this code alone could cause a discrepancy. Check the console for errors.

Comment: The code looks okay, what type of element is `[data-async-url]` btw?

Comment: It is used to link to the external html <div data-async-url="url/to/index.html"></div>

Comment: $this.data('async-url');, shouldn´t it be $this.data('[data-async-url]'); ???

Answer (score 0):

Initiate it like this:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        function async(){
            $('[data-async-url]').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    url = $this.data('async-url');
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    type: 'get',
                    success: function(html) {
                        $this.replaceWith(html);
                    }
                });
            });
        };
        $().ready(function () {
           async();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```